# java replace functionality

Tags: java, replace

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = "this is just just a text text";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(" just ", " <b>just</b> "));
}
```

The output should be this is **just** **just** a text text, but I am getting this is **just** just a text text. Can somebody help me understanding this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: use this: System.out.println(s.replaceAll(" just", " <b>just</b> "));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing something like :

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("just", "<b>just</b>"));
```

could not be suitable if you want only replace `"just"` and not any word starting by `"just"`.
Otherwise an input like :

```
String s = "this is justice just a text text";
```

will produce :

> this is **just** ice **just**  a text text

As `replaceAll()` uses a regex, you could handle the whitespace by expecting `" just"` or `"just "`.

By doing it :

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\sjust|just\\s", "<b>just</b>"));
```

you will get a close result to your target but you will have still some issues with whitespaces (too many or not enough) in the output as the regex takes into consideration the white space before or after and to keep the replacement consistent you should keep the whitespace as it was in input.

A finer solution would be to invoke twice `replaceAll()` :

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(" just ", " <b>just</b> ").replaceAll(" just ", " <b>just</b> "));
```

For example with this input :

```
String s = "this is a just just just adjusted justice test";
```

The first `replaceAll()` replaces chained " just " once every two :

```
this is a <b>just</b> just <b>just</b> adjusted justice test
```

> this is a **just** just **just** adjusted justice test

And the second `replaceAll()` invoked on the String returned by the first `replaceAll()` replaces the remaining `" just "` :

```
this is a <b>just</b> <b>just</b> <b>just</b> adjusted justice test
```

> this is a **just** **just** **just** adjusted justice test

It gives an accurate result but it is not the most effective way as it parses twice the String.

A more effective solution could use a `Pattern`and define a group that doesn't include the whitespace. In this way the replacement may be performed only on the `just` String.

Comment: I wanted to replace with only words, it can not be suffix or prefix of any other word.

Comment: I understand your point. I tried to improve my answer as even if it was on the right way and you accepted it, the proposed solution was not accurate according to your requirement. I illustrated with a more complete input sample.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("just", "<b>just</b>"));
```

Notice missing spaces in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It is because both whitespaces `\s` are consumed with first `\sjust\s`, so there is only `just\s` left in string thus `\sjust\s` will not match

`s.replaceAll(" just", "<b>just</b>")` will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing `just` (**notice the white space before and after "just"**), and in `this is just just a text text` there is only 1 such instance, you can better do `s.replaceAll("just", "<b>just</b>")`, which basically means simply use "just" and "**just**", **without any white space**.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it is not finding the second just because there is not a double space in between just and just such as " just  just"  because it only finds one " just " using the middle space once and not allowing it to be used again as a found match for the replace function.

Answer (score 0):

this shoudl work and if you look closely you see that i am using a white space inf the  " just"

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(" just", "<b>just</b>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra white space . instead of 
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(" just ", " **just** ")); you should use
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("just", "**just**"));

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, no one has pointed out that you should use a word boundary:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\bjust\\b", "<b>just</b>"));
```

By using a word boundary, you don’t have to depend on whitespace and you don’t need the complexity of multiple replaceAll calls.